# Logback error on graalvm with IfAction conditions

Tags: logback, graalvm

I am trying to make a serverless lambda with HTTP4K with SLF4J logback logging on graalvm. Everything works fine except that I get in my logging the following error:

```
14:33:21,581 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
14:33:21,581 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [resource:logback.xml]
14:33:21,583 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.ConfigurationWatchList@7eab6883 - URL [resource:logback.xml] is not of type file
14:33:21,647 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - debug attribute not set
14:33:21,663 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.ShutdownHookAction - About to instantiate shutdown hook of type [ch.qos.logback.core.hook.DelayingShutdownHook]
14:33:21,670 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
14:33:21,670 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [consoleAppender]
14:33:21,675 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
14:33:21,724 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.conditional.IfAction - Failed to parse condition [property("ENVIRONMENT").equals("production") || property("ENVIRONMENT").equals("acceptance")] org.codehaus.commons.compiler.InternalCompilerException: SNO: Generated compilation unit does not declare class 'SC'
at org.codehaus.commons.compiler.InternalCompilerException: SNO: Generated compilation unit does not declare class 'SC'
```

Graalvm also has the following warning when creating a native-image:

```
Could not resolve SC for reflection configuration. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: SC
```

While the SC was added in with the agentlib scan (`java -agentlib:native-image-agent=config-merge-dir=`) like this:

```
{
  "name":"SC",
  "methods":[{"name":"<init>","parameterTypes":[] }]
}
```

With the following code in logback:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration scan="true">
    <shutdownHook class="ch.qos.logback.core.hook.DelayingShutdownHook" />

    <variable scope="context" name="mdcPattern" value="%replace(%n %mdc){'[^$]+ ( |$)', ''}"/>
    <appender name="consoleAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>
            <Pattern>%magenta(%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS}) [%green(%thread)] %highlight(%-5level) [%yellow(%logger{0})] - %msg %throwable ${mdcPattern} %n</Pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <if condition='property("ENVIRONMENT").equals("production") || property("ENVIRONMENT").equals("acceptance")'>
        <then>
            ...
        </then>
    </if>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

It worked fine without errors without graalvm enabled so was wondering if certain configuration is needed to make it work correctly on graalvm. (When removing the if statement in logback there are no errors anymore)

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was causing this or how to resolve it? I'm running into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had same error and was managed to resolve this by adding this in my logback.xml:

```
<statusListener class="ch.qos.logback.core.status.NopStatusListener" />
```

And using your file it will be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration scan="true">
    .... Here ....
    <statusListener class="ch.qos.logback.core.status.NopStatusListener" /> 
    ..............
    <shutdownHook class="ch.qos.logback.core.hook.DelayingShutdownHook" />

    <variable scope="context" name="mdcPattern" value="%replace(%n %mdc){'[^$]+ ( |$)', ''}"/>
    <appender name="consoleAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>
            <Pattern>%magenta(%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS}) [%green(%thread)] %highlight(%-5level) [%yellow(%logger{0})] - %msg %throwable ${mdcPattern} %n</Pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <if condition='property("ENVIRONMENT").equals("production") || property("ENVIRONMENT").equals("acceptance")'>
        <then>
            ...
        </then>
    </if>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

More over it removed all logback own status (INFO or WARN) at the start of the program. Thanks to [MKyong blog](https://mkyong.com/logging/how-to-stop-logback-status-info-at-the-start-of-every-log/)

Hopefully it will help someone.